# How to apply css with jquery outside from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, popup

I am using iframe popup and i want to change something outside of iframe with jquery from iframe ?

this need to be done with jquery.

code like this

```
<iframe> <div  id="change">Change css</div> </iframe>
<div class="outer-div"> Text goes here </div>

<script>
$("#change").live('click', function(){
           $('#outer-div').css('display','none');
});
<script>
```

i want to hide of outer div click on iframe inner div

thanks
Simranjeet singh

Comment: You cannot access an iframe from outside it.

Comment: We don't have magic wands here, you need to show code, or make a fiddle

Comment: depends on the change you are expecting , anyways you can try making an ajax call from within the iframe , which goes out of the iframe and makes the changes you want . still depends on your needs ,not sure whether it will work 100%

Comment: and yes making a fiddle is the best way to ask something like this here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

This is some code that has worked for me.

Assuming that the iFrame is within the same domain as it's parent, try this:

```
// -- Find the PARENT of the iFrame that this script runs in
var $topLevel = $(window.parent.document, window.parent.document);
```

If you then use $topLevel as a starting point for your jQuery it *should* work.

Be aware that this codes works alright in modern browsers but doesn't seem to operate in IE8 (and untested below IE8)